# How to get square effect rather than ripple on android BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, xml, layout, navigation, bottomnavigationview

What I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm aiming to get:

[image]

I got the first one by adding this to my build.gralde:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
```

And then this to my layout xml:

```
<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:id="@+id/bottomView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
            android:background="#f8f8f8"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom layout for BottomNavigationView. And your layout's clickable parent should contain attribute **android:background="?selectableItemBackground"** .
Below is an example.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sel" />
```

This will give experience of rectangular Ripple above kitkat and normal rectangle below and on kitkat . If you do not want ripple at all(In all android versions). the use a selector as background like .

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#4C000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Use this instead .

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="?selectableItemBackground"
    />
```

Comment: And yes I'm aiming for the rectangular ripple effect

Comment: Use it now . it shuld work . I can not test my self it right now but give it a try and let me know .

Comment: I have this:

<LinearLayout>
   <FrameLayout />
   <BottomNavigationViewEx />
</LinearLayout>

I've added android:background="?selectableItemBackground" to the LinearLayout, and still getting same rounded ripple effected (no rectangle)

Comment: It worked when I added app:itemBackground="?selectableItemBackground" to the BottomNavigationView. Thanks a lot!

Comment: see the update answer .hahaha thats what i just updated . Sorry it took me some time to identify . Thx